# Как правильно задать высоту колонке равной её содержимому (CSS Grid Layout)?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

На примере видно, что высота колонок равна высоте самой большой колонки. Как задать высоту, чтобы высота была равна содержимому этой колонки?

Работает, если дочернему элементу задать `height: max-content;`, но вероятно есть стандартный метод для этой задачи?

```css
*
{
  paddong: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper
{
  width: 600px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 15px;
}

.wrapper > div
{
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    Даже всемогущая пунктуация не имеет власти над рыбными текстами, ведущими безорфографичный образ жизни.
  </div>
  <div>
    Даже всемогущая пунктуация не имеет власти над рыбными текстами, ведущими безорфографичный образ жизни.
  </div>
  <div>
    Взобравшись на первую вершину курсивных гор, бросил он последний взгляд назад, на силуэт своего родного города Буквоград, на заголовок деревни Алфавит и на подзаголовок своего переулка Строчка. Грустный реторический вопрос скатился по его щеке и он продолжил свой путь.
  </div>
</div
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid: 600px auto / 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.wrapper>div {
  background: orange;
  align-self: start;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    Даже всемогущая пунктуация не имеет власти над рыбными текстами, ведущими безорфографичный образ жизни.
  </div>
  <div>
    Даже всемогущая пунктуация не имеет власти над рыбными текстами, ведущими безорфографичный образ жизни.
  </div>
  <div>
    Взобравшись на первую вершину курсивных гор, бросил он последний взгляд назад, на силуэт своего родного города Буквоград, на заголовок деревни Алфавит и на подзаголовок своего переулка Строчка. Грустный реторический вопрос скатился по его щеке и он продолжил
    свой путь.
  </div>
</div>
```

Обратите внимание, что у вас опечатка в обнулении паддингов и марджинов.

Фиддл https://jsfiddle.net/76yy4cyw/11/

Вот тут отличный тьюториал https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

**Решение 2.**

Кстати говоря, в вашем случае сработали бы и флоаты

```css
**CSS** * {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper>div {
  background: orange;
  width: 190px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.wrapper>div:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    Даже всемогущая пунктуация не имеет власти над рыбными текстами, ведущими безорфографичный образ жизни.
  </div>
  <div>
    Даже всемогущая пунктуация не имеет власти над рыбными текстами, ведущими безорфографичный образ жизни.
  </div>
  <div>
    Взобравшись на первую вершину курсивных гор, бросил он последний взгляд назад, на силуэт своего родного города Буквоград, на заголовок деревни Алфавит и на подзаголовок своего переулка Строчка. Грустный реторический вопрос скатился по его щеке и он продолжил
    свой путь.
  </div>
</div>
```

Фиддл https://jsfiddle.net/76yy4cyw/14/

Но в этом случае нет адаптивности при ширине основного блока меньше 600 пикселов.

Comment: `align-self: start;` - точно! Помню, когда-то давно уже решал подобную задачу именно таким способом, спасибо!
Кстати, зачем использовать `margin-right: 15px;` и `div:last-child > margin-right: 0;` если есть базовый метод от гридов `grid-gap: 15px;` ?

Comment: Это код для решения на флоатах

Answer (score 0):

Можно выравнивать элементы grid контейнера по оси Y с помощью `align-items`.
`Heidel` привел пример на гридах, когда ты обращаешься к элементу в контейнере поточечно и выравниваешь его по оси грид контейнера

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(150px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 15px;
  align-items: start;
}

.wrapper > div {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    Даже всемогущая пунктуация не имеет власти над рыбными текстами, ведущими безорфографичный образ жизни.
  </div>
  <div>
    Даже всемогущая пунктуация не имеет власти над рыбными текстами, ведущими безорфографичный образ жизни.
  </div>
  <div>
    Взобравшись на первую вершину курсивных гор, бросил он последний взгляд назад, на силуэт своего родного города Буквоград, на заголовок деревни Алфавит и на подзаголовок своего переулка Строчка. Грустный реторический вопрос скатился по его щеке и он продолжил
    свой путь.
  </div>
</div>
```